# Calling postMessage in Web Worker onmessage callback throws SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

Tags: javascript, postmessage, web-worker, worker, domexception

When writing the onmessage callback for a Web Worker I get an "Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12" in my console when I try to send another postMessage().

```
var w = new Worker(url);
w.onmessage = function(e) {
    if(e.data.msg=='validate'){
        if(validateWork(e.data.wrk)){
            postMessage('proceed');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already figured this out, but I couldn't find any help when I Googled, so I wanted to share. Please ask questions if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: To the guy who downvoted both the question and the answer; you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call postMessage() using this when in a callback.

```
this.postMessage('proceed');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work too:

w.postMessage('proceed');